# Array Generating Images

Tags: arrays, actionscript

I'm not overly sure if this is possible, as I am not a frequent programmer, but I have a question.

I've got an array that generates one random word in a text box and then a second array that generates another random word in a different text box. What I want is for when a certain word out of array number one is generated, a certain image appears with it. Here's the code:

```
var firstChoice:Array = ["Do this", "Do that", "Do something else"];
var secondOption:Array = ["while doing this", "while doing that", "while doing something else"];
generate_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getTask);

function getTask(event:MouseEvent):void {
var randomChoice:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * firstChoice.length);
var randomOption:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * secondOption.length);
Final_Choice.text = firstChoice[randomChoice];
Final_Option.text = secondOption[randomOption];
}
```

So for instance, when I click the button and the first array generates "Do this," I want a specific graphic to appear with it.

Hopefully this is possible :/  I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to use a HashMap, such as:

```
var map:Object = new Object();
map.first_choice = /*url of your image associated with this choice*/
map.second_choice = /*url of your image associated with this choice*/
//etc
```

and when a word is generated, you just compare the word with keys of the map, using a foreach, and get the url of your image